# quartz cron scheduling where does it read triggers

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

I have a few quartz triggers set-up in my xml file, that has been running for a while now.
dailytrigger
weeklytrigger
and 
monthlytrigger

But I have now added a forth, and am not getting the 4th trigger I have added firing with all triggers in the xml file.
But if it is on its own, it fires every time.
I also see a trigger firing even thought I don't have it defined in the xml file, so I wondered where else Quartz gets its triggers from?

Comment: Regarding the trigger that fires, but that is not present in your XML. If you have configured Quartz to use a JDBC job store, then you have to remove the trigger from the job store manually using an SQL query. This is how Quartz works - it does not sync the current list of triggers (in your case defined in the XML file) with the DB. It is because the DB can contain trigger that have been added programmatically etc. What we do in our Spring apps is that upon every app startup, we purge all jobs and triggers from the Quartz DB and let the app bootstrap the current list of jobs and triggers.

Comment: Jan - that sounds great, and we have got a JDBC job store I have now found, thanks for that.
I'd also like to add, I wasn't getting all triggers firing because we have 2 separate systems running off the same database, and Quartz from the other system acquired the trigger, so my system didn't pick it up, it thought it was already being executed, as we also have it set as a distributed system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is it depends on the configuration of quartz,
we configured to use the JDBC job store, 
this reads the xml and puts the triggers in the database if not already there.
then if they change in the database the trigger changes in quartz, so it is what is in the database that defines what will trigger.